# Database export throwing SystemOutOfMemory exception

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to export a SQL Azure database to Azure storage using the Azure portal.

For some reason I am getting the following error every time I try to export the database:

Error encountered during the service operation. Could not export schema and data from database. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Previous backups of this database have resulted in a bacpac file of 112 MB.  The database is currently 2.62 GB in size.

Other smaller databases have backed up successfully today, it's just this larger database that continually fails with this error.

Any ideas what I can do to get this working?

Comment: If it is the portal that throws that error, I think a support case with Microsoft may be your best option. Not a whole lot of options to tweak there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has now been resolved.

The portal has been our normal route to performing backups, as it's performed numerous backups without any hiccups.  However, as the failure offered little more than OutOfMemoryException, we reverted back to the SSMS backup option [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx) (something we should have done prior to raising this question), which, although still failed, highlighted the problem was data related and not the portal.

The actual issue relates to a single xml column in a single table - SSMS highlighted the table that failed.  Thankfully, the data is transient, should be regularly deleted and does not need to be backed up.

We have since performed the required maintenance and as a result been able to do a full backup.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if it was the sheer number of rows with xml, or just that Azure doesn't like xml columns at all?